# js comparing elements to zero returning false result

Tags: javascript

I have a list of floats and want to check if all of them are negative.

When I loop through my list that is :  el = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -34.470000000000006], I get true, but it should be false.

```
var weekly_plus_perfs = true;

for (var el = 0; el < weekly_plus.length; el++) {
    if (weekly_plus[el]>0) {
        weekly_plus_perfs = false;
    }
}
```

Where am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the test to `>=`

None of these numbers are more than zero. The original condition, TRUE, remains.

Answer (score 0):

You could check with `>=` and exit if a false value is found.

```js
var weekly_plus = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -34.470000000000006],
    weekly_plus_perfs = true,

for (var el = 0; el < weekly_plus.length; el++) {
    if (weekly_plus[el] >= 0) {
        weekly_plus_perfs = false;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(weekly_plus_perfs);
```

ES5 with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
var weekly_plus = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -34.470000000000006],
    weekly_plus_perfs = weekly_plus.every(function (v) {
        return v < 0;
    });

console.log(weekly_plus_perfs);
```

ES6

```js
var weekly_plus = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -34.470000000000006],
    weekly_plus_perfs = weekly_plus.every(v => v < 0);

console.log(weekly_plus_perfs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array also have an `every` function that evaluates if the condition is true for all elements in the list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

```js
var el = [0,1,0,-13]; 
var el2 = [1,2,3,4];
console.log( el.every((e)=>{return e >= 0;}) ); 
console.log( el2.every((e)=>{return e >= 0;}) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` is not negative, so the test should be better understood as:

```
var weekly_plus_perfs = false;
for(var el=0; el<weekly_plus.length;el++){
  if(weekly_plus[el] < 0){
    weekly_plus_perfs = true;
 }}
```

But, the **[`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** method is a better fit for this problem:

```js
console.log([-12, -5, 0, -5, 44].every(function (element, index, array) { 
  return element < 0; 
}));   // false 


console.log([-12, -54, -18, -130, -44].every(function (element, index, array) { 
  return element < 0; 
})); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Array.every()` and `isNaN()` functions:

```js
var list = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -34.470000000000006];
    all_negative = list.every(function(n) { return !isNaN(n) && n < 0; });
 
console.log(all_negative);
```